# Random environment runtime generation in Unity

Tags: unity, procedural-generation

I need a tip for a project: basically I need to randomly generate an environment (a map) for a game. 
As generating a full map completely procedural is impossible for me, I thought to create a static map (I made one ice based, one rock based, one desert based etc) with some static elements in it like a "spawn area", a map border.

Next, I made some "piece of map" smaller that the actual size of the border (like the border is 1000x1000 and this piece are max 200x200). Each piece has the same style of the border (e.g. I made few icy pieces with a spawn of polar bear and few desert pieces with a spawn of scorpions).

Now I'm stuck; I can't randomly spawn all the little squares inside a border & I can't randomly spawn them inside and make them match one with an other. Incidentally, this is a 3D project.

Comment: Why is it that you "can't random spawn all the little square inside a border" ? What specific issue is blocking you from achieving what you want? The better you can describe (or better, show) what your obstacle is, the easier we can help you overcome it.

Comment: A screenshot or mock up of a failed result would also be helpful.

Comment: Firs of all, thanks for the interest of helping me. I have no idea to randomly "spawn" 3D tiles into a specific area of the map. The square are prefab and they contain a spawn for the enemy, a static object for decoration, nav mesh already baked, etc. I don't know a function that allowed me to physically put this prefab (I have 50 different for each type of environment) into a 3D area with a static border. As all of this piece has to match together. Then I would like to know how to let the system know to use some of those prefabs with a higher priority

Comment: Example: the prefabs that contain Power Up has to spawn less that the prefabs that contain just enemy and more than the prefabs that contain a "Boss". Unfortunately, I can't make any screenshot as I don't know the function that I need for. I'm quite new unity programming world for a 3D application and (I hope) there is a function that can help me. I just don't know which one is it. Many thanks beforehand for your help

Comment: If you take a look at the "Random Tidbits" section of [Math for Game Programmers](http://www.mathforgameprogrammers.com), there's a section about how to create the random distribution you want. (I think it's the slides labelled "Sculpt Your Own Distribution".) It allows you to do things like use a random number generator and have 10% of the results generate power ups, but have enemies 25% of the time, or whatever. There's pseudo-code on the slides.

Comment: This sounds like a straightforward application of the `Instantiate(prefab, position, rotation)` method with a prefab [selected randomly from a weighted distribution](https://gamedev.stackexchange.com/q/60299/39518). Can you edit your question to explain which of these steps you know how to do, and exactly where you're running into trouble?

Comment: Thanks! I'll have a look at the link in your answer and then I'll let you know. @DMGregory what you suggest is to Instantiate random prefabs for a list (maybe I can make the array of prefabs) and put it in the random position with a random rotation (just 0, 90, 180 angles as they are square). But how can I make sure that the random position will be correct? If the position will be random, then 2 prefabs could be in the same position or the next prefabs that the system spawn could be on top of the previous one. I have a problem by correctly spawn the prefabs in a determinate 3D area.

Comment: If you're selecting a prefab at random, then why randomize the position? Just step through your positions in order, and select a random prefab for each one. That way you guarantee no overlaps because you control the spacing precisely.

Comment: Shure! But how can I select a position in a 3D world? 
My border is 1020x1020 where the last 20 (10 units for each border) are covered by a static border. So just 1000x1000 is usable for spawn all the prefabs tiles. I made all the tiles 50x50 for make it easier for me put them in the map. What you suggest is: 
1- Random pick my prefabs tiles using a random method that we figured out above
2-  Starting from the position 10, 0, 10 (x, y, z) spawn the first prefab with a random rotation 0, 90, 180.
3- Go in the position 60, 0, 60 and spawn the second random prefabs?

Comment: I can try by doing this method. Or you suggest another way that allowed me to have a better result with less code?
In any case thanks to open my mind and (probably) solve my problem! :D

Comment: If you need help on stepping through a grid of positions in 3D space, I'd recommend editing your question to describe that problem, what you know how yo do so far, and what part you don't know / isn't working the way you want yet.